# How to make an animation with Candlestick from plotly (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Esteemed,

I can make plots with `Candlestick` from [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly).
However, inside a loop, how to make these figures not be created one below the other, but all in one figure? Creating an animation effect.
See the example where I plot candles with a window of 5 days ahead, successively, going through the entire DataFrame.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

#df
#i         Date   AAPL.Open   AAPL.High    AAPL.Low  AAPL.Close  AAPL.Volume  \
#0    2015-02-17  127.489998  128.880005  126.919998  127.830002     63152400   
#1    2015-02-18  127.629997  128.779999  127.449997  128.720001     44891700  
#....

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    FiveDaysBlock = df.iloc[index:(index+5),]

    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(
    x=FiveDaysBlock['Date'],
    open=FiveDaysBlock['AAPL.Open'], high=FiveDaysBlock['AAPL.High'],
    low=FiveDaysBlock['AAPL.Low'], close=FiveDaysBlock['AAPL.Close']
    )])
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
    fig.update_layout(autosize=False,width=700, height=250, margin=dict( l=1,r=1,b=20,  t=20, pad=2 ) )
    fig.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"])])
    fig.show()
```

[image: See how the figure is generated under the other]

Thank you,

Comment: Do you want the next FiveDaysBlock to replace the current one for each step of the animation?

Comment: @DerekO Yes, I would like.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same these days and finallly I did this:

[image: Animated candles]

The code here:

https://github.com/matiaslee/candlestick_animation_with_plotly/blob/main/candlestick_animation_with_plotly.ipynb

Best!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, based on [this open issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1876), it seems that the x-axis and y-axis autoscaling is disabled with a go.Candlestick() object so the axes won't scale properly as the animation progresses.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

#df
#i         Date   AAPL.Open   AAPL.High    AAPL.Low  AAPL.Close  AAPL.Volume  \
#0    2015-02-17  127.489998  128.880005  126.919998  127.830002     63152400   
#1    2015-02-18  127.629997  128.779999  127.449997  128.720001     44891700  
#....

# it might be useful to convert the Dates to datetime objects
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

candlestick_data = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    FiveDaysBlock = df.iloc[index:(index+5),]
    candlestick_data.append(go.Candlestick(x=FiveDaysBlock['Date'],
        open=FiveDaysBlock['AAPL.Open'], high=FiveDaysBlock['AAPL.High'],
        low=FiveDaysBlock['AAPL.Low'], close=FiveDaysBlock['AAPL.Close'])
    )

def update_fig(i):
    fig = go.Figure(data=candlestick_data[i])

    fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
    fig.update_layout(transition_duration=2000)
    fig.update_layout(autosize=True,width=700, height=250, margin=dict(l=1,r=1,b=20,t=20,pad=2))

# this doesn't quite work but it's close
interact(update_fig, i=100)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Dear @DerekO,

Thank you for your attention in the response.
Unfortunately it won't be a viable process to have to click on the [Autoscale] button.
If it is not possible to make an animation, would there be a "forward" and "backward" button to scroll through the list of 5-day windows?

My best,

Comment: I have a feeling that using the go.Candlestick() object, you will run into problems because the axes cannot be resized as an animation or frames progress. Therefore, you will have the draw the boxes from each frame manually. If I have the time, I can certainly give it a try. Best, Derek

Comment: I got it, thanks. Would it be possible to use an interactive slider to scroll through the created windows? without using animation. Example: https://blog.dominodatalab.com/interactive-dashboards-in-jupyter/

Comment: To be honest, I don't have experience creating an interactive dashboard in Jupyter, but the "Interact" feature looks promising. You can scrap the Plotly animation, and instead use the interactive slider to change the output of the Candlestick chart. I'll update my answer to get you started if you want a guide.

Comment: The way I have it written right now, the interact button doesn't update the figure that is showing. This may have something to do with the backend of plotly: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7520

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working...returns: AttributeError: module 'plotly.graph_objects' has no attribute 'show'