# Plotly Candlestick Flickering when animating with an additional trace

Tags: plotly, candlestick-chart

I've been able to animate plotly candlesticks which works fine but when I try to add a line trace on it, I get a flickering candlestick but the line trace animates just fine.

Is there any work around?

Here's my code which is a modification of a response from @matiaslee found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62014665/how-to-make-an-animation-with-candlestick-from-plotly-python)

```
### my attempt
play_button = {
    "args": [
        None, 
        {
            "frame": {"duration": 300, "redraw": True},
            "fromcurrent": True, 
            "transition": {"duration": 100,"easing": "quadratic-in-out"}
        }
    ],
    "label": "Play",
    "method": "animate"
}

pause_button = {
    "args": [
        [None], 
        {
            "frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": False},
            "mode": "immediate",
            "transition": {"duration": 0}
        }
    ],
    "label": "Pause",
    "method": "animate"
}

sliders_steps = [
    {"args": [
        [0, i], # 0, in order to reset the image, i in order to plot frame i
        {"frame": {"duration": 300, "redraw": True},
         "mode": "immediate",
         "transition": {"duration": 300}}
    ],
    "label": i,
    "method": "animate"}
    for i in range(len(raw_candles))      
]

sliders_dict = {
    "active": 0,
    "yanchor": "top",
    "xanchor": "left",
    "currentvalue": {
        "font": {"size": 20},
        "prefix": "frame:",
        "visible": True,
        "xanchor": "right"
    },
    "transition": {"duration": 300, "easing": "cubic-in-out"},
    "pad": {"b": 10, "t": 50},
    "len": 0.9,
    "x": 0.1,
    "y": 0,
    "steps": sliders_steps,
}

fig =  go.Figure(go.Candlestick(
    x=raw_candles.index, 
    open=raw_candles.open, 
    high=raw_candles.high, 
    low=raw_candles.low, 
    close=raw_candles.close,
    name='candles'
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=raw_candles.index, y= raw_candles.ema21,
              line={'color':'red', 'width':1},     
              mode='lines',
              name='ema21'))

#Store Names and their corresponding order of the 
nameDataindexdict={}
for dt in fig.data:
    nameDataindexdict[dt['name']]=fig.data.index(dt)

frames = []

for i in range(len(raw_candles)):
    frames.append(go.Frame(data=[go.Candlestick(
                                x=raw_candles.index[:i], 
                                open=raw_candles.open[:i], 
                                high=raw_candles.high[:i], 
                                low=raw_candles.low[:i], 
                                close=raw_candles.close[:i]
                            ),
                                 go.Scatter(x=raw_candles.index, y= raw_candles.ema21[:i],
                                      line={'color':'red', 'width':1},     
                                      mode='lines',
                                      name='ema21'
                                           )],
                        
                                traces=[nameDataindexdict['candles'],nameDataindexdict['ema21']],    
                                name=f"fr{i}"
                                ))     
    

fig.update(frames=frames) 

fig.update_layout(
                  updatemenus=[dict(type="buttons", buttons=[play_button, pause_button])],
                  sliders=[sliders_dict])
fig.show()
```

Attached gif is my output.